# How do you discover passcodes?

Tags: ingress

I've seen hints that media files can give you codes but I haven't been able top figure or any from the media I have. How does it work?

Comment: Here is an audio media I received today from hacking.  I already looked at the metadata and source and have no idea.  Please post your results if you figure it out:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/objx/lrg/555h5.mp3

Comment: @rwyland I have the same media file, but no idea where to start

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right now all working passcodes I know are the one being published by Niatic Labs in twitter.

Here is the [document](http://goo.gl/nZ2AH) which contains all known passcodes. All of passcodes should still be applicable and can be used by each player only one.

I recommend you use http://ingress.com/intel to apply them.

Would be extremely interesting to try to hack documents you get for codes, but so far I had no success.

**Update: some very clever guys from Berlin resistance have found a way how to hack these document, this is the result:**

> 11/19/2012: Sensitives (SOLVED)
>   http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pac/IB/00/item/Sensitives1.png
>
> Binary code is encoded in the right margin of the document.
>
> Replace...
>   Dots with 0
>   Dash with 1
>   Equal sign with 11
>
> ...to get: 0110000101100110011100100110000101101101001100010011001101110100
>
> Convert binary to ASCII to get: afram13t an #Ingress passcode
>
> An uncensored version of this document was obtained from portal hacking by  Ingress >players.  The faint text in the enhanced image (attached in this album) is lifted from >page 2 of the doc, which was also obtained by hacking.
>
> Page 1:
>   http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/objx/lrg/Sensitives1.png
>
> Page 2:
>   http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/objx/lrg/Sensitives2.png
>
> Page 2 contains an ADA image hidden in the Niantic logo.

Comment: Looks like the doc method wont work much longer. http://ingressfieldguide.com/?q=content/changes-ingress-passcodes

Comment: Might want to update this answer to reflect the fact that the passcodes are now expired and can't be used.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently you need to find the code somewhere in the media.

For example, [this page](http://decodeingress.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/pandora-decoded-with-new-passcode/) describes how the passcode *ezekiel27w* was recovered from a media by converting a string of digits in the header from decimal to ASCII.

*(This means that those with full time jobs are unlikely to benefit from many passcodes)*

Answer (score 5):

### Official Methods

- (obsolete) The [Investigation Board](http://www.nianticproject.com/) released new media containing clues which can be decoded to reveal passcodes, but it's ancient now. So no luck there. But you can still see the way people decoded them in [these](http://niantic.schlarp.com/investigation:ingress_clues) [docs](http://goo.gl/y7KO7).
- Follow the [Ingress Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress), there are often clues in the pictures
- Watch [Ingress Reports](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDEUWItbkQ58tbLEFP6lA1PtnPk48jDBr), there may be clues there too
- Get in touch with local faction members - they are what the game is made for, and often your best source of support
- Some bottles of [HINT water](https://blog.drinkhint.com/its-time-to-move-with-hint-ingress/) have codes under the cap!

### Unofficial Methods

#### Communities

- [Decode Ingress](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114606795989653285746) will reveal hints and tips on ***how*** to decode.
- [Ingress Passcodes](https://plus.google.com/communities/108599095839806789745)

#### Databases

These are generally discouraged as it takes the fun out of decoding.

- [Ingress Field Guide Passcode Database](http://ingressfieldguide.com/passcodes)
- [IngressCodes Twitter](https://twitter.com/IngressCodes)

### Resources

- [Common formats for passcodes](http://niantic.schlarp.com/investigation:apps:ingress:passcodes)
- Some tools to help in decoding - [Cipher Tools](http://decodeingress.me/tools/), [Decode Ingress Tools](http://decodeingress.me/tools/)